# Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm trying for Accessing data From Wcf-Rest Service in Mvc through an Angular Js But when i try to binding data Its Throughing an Error as Error: `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: ee in HelloData, Duplicate key: string:r, Duplicate value: r`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tab-content">
            <tr>
                <th><b>Id</b></th>
                <th><b>Name</b></th>
               </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="ee in HelloData"> 
                <td>{{ee.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{ee.Name}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

**Ctrl.Js**

```
$scope.CallServiceDb = function () {
            alert('in cntrl');
            var sss = MywcfService.GetData();
            sss.then(function (d) {
                $scope.HelloData = d.data;
            })
```

**Service.Js**

```
 var RestApi = "http://localhost:9706/EmployeeService.svc";

this.GetData = function () {
        alert('in Service');
        var sss = $http({
            url: RestApi+"/Hell",
            method: "GET",
         })
        return sss;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track by $index if your data source has duplicate identifiers,

```
<tr ng-repeat="ee in HelloData track by $index"> 
   <td>{{ee.Id}}</td>
   <td>{{ee.Name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: when i use  ee in HelloData track by $index    I'm getting soomany Empty Lines But i have only 4Lines of data

Comment: Probably those does not have id and name

Comment: i'm getting data Like this ArrayOfxyz xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication.Data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><xyz><Email>hhh@gmail.com</Email><Gen>Male</Gen><Id>1</Id><Name>Ghouse</Name><Psw>123</Psw><Village>amb</Village></xyz><xyz

Comment: can you post the json here

Comment: <xyz>
<Email>hhh@gmail.com</Email>
<Gen>Male</Gen>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Ghouse</Name>
<Psw>123</Psw>
<Village>amb</Village>
</xyz>

Comment: above one is not a json

Comment: I Think its in Xml format thats y i'm getting an Error is it correct Sir

Comment: pease tell me how to access Xml Data

Comment: Hello sir please tell me how to access data if data comes in XmlFormat Its Most Important 4r me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134198/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-md-dastageerjob).